# Как парсить csv json-парсером от OKTELL

Tags: javascript, java, json, json.net

Товарищи, ниже у меня есть пример, для парсера в Oktell, как мне заставить его читать файл .csv?

```
 {
      "info": {
        "list1": {
          "index": 1,
          "name": "matrix",
          "rows": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "row1",
              "cols": [
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "name": "element11"
                },
                {
                  "id": "2",
                  "name": "element12"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "row2",
              "cols": [
                {
                  "id": "1",
                  "name": "element21"
                },
                {
                  "id": "2",
                  "name": "element22"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Вот что описано на wiki: 
В документе описана матрица 2x2, которая находится на первом листе в info.

Oktell имеет собственный синтаксис разбора JSON-объектов. В принципе синтаксис простейший: доступ к значению идет по имени в кавычках, доступ к вложенным объектам — через /, доступ к элементу массива по индексу. В качестве примера, рассмотрим следующие запросы:

"info"/"list1"/"name" - получить значение по имени name у объекта list1 в объекте info. Запрос вернет: "matrix".
"info"/"list1"/"rows"/1/"name" - получить значение по имени name у второго элемента (отсчет элемент начинается с нуля) в массиве rows. Запрос вернет "row2".
"info"/"list1"/"rows"/1/"cols"/0/"name" - получить значение по имени name у первого элемента в массиве cols у второй строки на первом листе. Запрос вернет "element21"

Comment: Три "сюжетные" линии вопроса расходятся. Код ниже - нет кода. Или сsv можно парисить средствами json? Не слышал... Парсить json, а оказывается csv... Или не csv...

Comment: Наверное я не правильно описал. 
Есть файл "Users.csv" В нем лист "Users" 
Есть "N" - количество строк. И 6 столбцов. Средствами встроенного парсера, мне нужно взять данные из файла..

Comment: Если бы я знал, как это работает, сюда бы не стал писать, уж поймите. Наверное всё очевидно, но я не могу связать эту инфу..

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вопрос звучит "Как парсить csv json-парсером от Oktell"... Не думаю что json парсер в качестве бонуса умеет csv парсить. Я Oktell не знаком... но мне кажется что тут что-то не то.

Comment: загрузите где-то файл, который нужно распарсить

Comment: Загрузил: https://dropmefiles.com/lQsWt

Comment: @ВадимНиколаевич что именно вам нужно получить? что Октелл должен сделать с данными в файле?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis В sql положить эти данные..

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Эта задача сложная сильно?

Comment: если честно, сейчас вообще не понимаю, в чем именно состоит задача. опишите весь сценарий. если нужно только загрузить данные из csv в ms sql - можно сделать это напрямую через студию. если важно сделать это через Oktell  - устанавливаете на сервере sql драйвер Excel и запросом из Oktell импортируете данные.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Задача следующая:

Информировать сотрудников, встроенными инструментами Oktell.
Для того чтобы это реализовать, необходимо создать на шаре файл users.csv в который будет вносить данные "Менеджер HR"

Из файла, встроенным парсером, данные идут в SQL а далее через запрос, эти данные достаются - выводятся пользователям.

Comment: @ВадимНиколаевич вам не нужен парсер Oktell. Можно использовать OLE подключение в компоненте SQL запрос, указавав в качестве источника ваш файла или же вызвать на сервере bulk insert, загрузить данные в таблицу и вернуть необходимый результат пользователям